# responsive css - stop image overlap when there is a large screen size

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Im creating a responsive html5 player and am currently designing the css. The problem i've hit is that the image will overlap the `.container` when viewed on a large screen and when viewed on a small screen does not fill the container. The image must always appear the same size on all screen sizes and must always fill (height wise) the container.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPdtT/). I've put it all in a div to emulate having different screen sizes, just change the width of it to have a look at what happens!

Answer (score 0):

just add a `<div>` element and set `clear` to `both`

example: http://jsfiddle.net/NPdtT/2/

Because you are floating elements, they do not get context, for such you need to clear (make sure that all of the above element will enter in a wrapper element - in your example the wrapper is `main_container`).

added: `<div class="clear"></div>` and `.clear { clear:both; }​`

Comment: Yes that fixes the problem of it overlapping but not the problem of it not filling the container when too small

Comment: for that, use a CSS Framework to help you out with a responsive design either [**Twitter Bootstrap**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) or [**Zurb Fundation**](http://foundation.zurb.com/) are the best choices.